# Spark on Yarn: driver memory is checked on the client side?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I thought I understood the spark on yarn architecture quite well but now I wonder: when I launch

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --class     com.domain.xxx.ddpaction.DdpApp --num-executors 24 --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 1 --conf "spark.yarn.jar=/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar" ddpaction-3.1.0.jar yarn-cluster config.yml
```

it fails with a

```
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 2863333376 bytes for committing reserved memory
```

The server from which I launch spark-submit has less than 2GB of free mem and this causes the error, but the resource manager, **where the driver should execute** has far more than the 4GB set as the driver-memory parameter.
Why does driver-memory value, that in my understanding should only be checked and allocated on the yarn cluster in the resource manager, is allocated on the server that launch spark-submit in yarn-cluster mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in Spark-1.4.0 See [SPARK-3884](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3884)

Comment: yes, I saw, I was one of the duplicate issue reporter :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a bad simplification in spark-submit script:

```
elif [ "$1" = "--driver-memory" ]; then
    export SPARK_SUBMIT_DRIVER_MEMORY=$2
```

So the driver memory param value is used by spark-submit to set its allocated memory; this is only right and needed in yarn-client mode, not in yarn-cluster.
I solved my problem by replacing those lines by:

```
elif [ "$1" = "--spark-submit-memory" ]; then
    export SPARK_SUBMIT_DRIVER_MEMORY=$2
```

so now I can set (if needed) the memory allocated to spark-submit to a different value of the one of the driver.